# export: Command not found

Tags: linux, shell

After typing `module load <module-name>` with a module that has the flask package, I started following the flask documentation instructions. I created the flaskr directory with a `__init__.py` file inside of it as instructed, and got the message

> export: Command not found.

when I type the command `export FLASK_APP=flaskr`.

I've love to hear ideas regarding what is missing or otherwise.
Thanks!

Comment: `export` is a built-in command of bash. Which shell are you using? For example, with fish shell, you would use `set` command with the right flags instead.

Comment: I used the command `echo "$SHELL"` and got the output `/bin/tcsh`

Comment: `export` is a command in Bourne-shell variants (`sh`, `bash`, `ksh`, etc). `tcsh` is a completely different beast. You should find documentation in `man tcsh`. Unless you're being forced to use it by circumstances outside of your control, I would switch to `bash`.

Comment: The equivalent in tcsh is `setenv FLASK_APP flaskr` (note no `=`)

Comment: Thank you both. I used the command `setenv` since I couldn't make the switch from tcsh to bash. Now flask works.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation which you are following assumes that you are using `bash` or a close variant. As you are in fact using `tcsh`, the equivalent syntax for setting an environment variable (i.e. a variable which is inherited by child processes) is:

```
setenv FLASK_APP flaskr
```

As `bash` shell is more commonly used these days, much online documentation may assume that that is what you are using, so it might be beneficial to use `bash` to align with this.  You can start a `bash` subshell just by typing `bash` (or `bash -login` to ensure that it reads any login scripts), but to change your login shell for future sessions, use the `chsh` command.